# Turn "Notify the persons before 30 days" into a question

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

I have the following sentence.

> Notify the persons before 30 days

How can I create a question for this sentence?

> Before how many days the persons should be notified?

Am I correct?

To make the question clearer: Suppose the Identity Card of a person is going to expire next month. The system needs to inform the person before 30 days. Does the word *within* match my requirement?

Answer (score 4):

No. Currently both sentences are incorrect. Firstly, "persons" is not the correct plural of "person". You probably want to use the word "people" or the singular "person".

For the first sentence, try something like this:

> Notify the **person within** 30 days

Or

> Notify the **people within** 30 days

You want the word "within" because you're relating to an implied time *range* (because it's 30 days from now), rather than an absolute date.

If you want to use **before**, you have to rephrase the sentence slightly:

> Notify the person **before he gets back from lunch**
>
> Notify the CEO **before the 5th of February**.

To turn it into a question, you need to alter the sentence thus:

> Within how many days should the person be notified?

Comment: OF course you could always go all out and ask, "What should I do to who when?" ;-)

Comment: .... to *whom* :)

Comment: yep, technically...

Comment: How about "Within how many days the person should be notified ?"

Comment: Its for a computer program. So the computer will send notification within 30 days.

Comment: @Rauf A better word-order is "Within how many days should the person be notified?". Note that a computer can also state "Within how many days should I notify the person?". See also http://ux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Matt Can you please address the modified question ?

Comment: @Rauf Gerrit is correct.  Your sentence is close to correct, but should read "Within how many days should the person be notified?"  The construction is "[after what event] should [this result occur]?"

Comment: Edit: Changed to better answer the modified question.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the help of '**in advance**' in this situation.

> "How many days in advance can I notify you?"